# Replace do AjaxBeginForm não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou utilizando um `Ajax.BeginForm` para atualizar uma div específica na página. Ao realizar o submit e executar a action, em vez de atualizar esta DIV, a página é atualizada com a partial view retornada da Action. Eu utilizo este mesmo trecho de código em um outro projeto e este funciona normalmente.

Já tentei reimportar as bibliotecas javascript para a partial view mas ainda assim o erro persiste.

Segue abaixo o trecho de código da inicialização do `Ajax.BeginForm`.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Bar", new AjaxOptions { 
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "Foo" 
})) 
{ 
// ... 
}
```

Comment: @Vinícius Como está sua configuração JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você adicionou o scripts:
~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Se não tiver no seu projeto, tem neste pacote:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Na sua Action, o retorno é uma PartialView?

Abs,